# JS: Proper way to use nested functions?

Tags: javascript

If I have an event listener and want to use a click event to target a function, would the preferred way to define that function be outside of the scope or can I make it nested within?

example:

```
function createNewDiv(str) {
   let target = document.getElementById('answer-500');
   target.addEventListener('click', addNewEl);

   function addNewEl() {
      // should it be defined here out as a new function in the same parent scope as `createNewDiv(str)`
   }
}
```

Comment: It depends on who you ask. Some people may prefer one way, while others prefer another.

Answer (score 2):

If the function depends on a variable *inside* `createNewDiv`, the function should usually be defined inside. For example, to log `str` inside, the function should also be inside:

```
function createNewDiv(str) {
   let target = document.getElementById('something');
   target.addEventListener('click', doLog);

   function doLog() {
      console.log(str);
   }
}
```

because `doLog` depends on having scope of `str`, the argument.

If the function *doesn't* depend on anything local to `createNewDiv`, then you can either put the function inside or outside, it might not matter.

If you want to be able to remove the listener later, from outside, the function should be defined outside, so that you could do `removeEventListener(elm, fn)`. (If the function is defined inside, that won't work unless the `removeEventListener` call is also lexically inside)

Putting the function outside may result in an usually insignificant performance improvement because that way the function only has to be created once (well, every time the outer block runs) rather than every time the `createNewDiv` runs.

If each such element will have no more than one listener attached to it, one possible method to use a single outer listener instead of multiple inner listeners would be to use a Map mapping each element to the associated `str`, eg:

```
const strsByElm = new Map();
function adNewEl() {
  const str = strsByElm.get(this);
  console.log(str);
}
function createNewDiv(str) {
   let target = document.getElementById('answer-500');
   target.addEventListener('click', addNewEl);
   strsByElm.set(target, str);
}
```

Comment: plus: if the scope outside createNewDiv is window, and you don't need to use function doLog outside it(like above curcumstances), you may define it inside not to pollute global scope window.